# plupload Does Not Want to Resize Image

Tags: javascript, plupload

I have problem with my plupload. I thought, I have been following all the documentation. Reading all the thread here but I do not find any answer. I really wish someone can help me out of this problem. Here is my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/plupload.full.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/i18n/id.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.js"></script>

var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
    runtimes:'html5',
    browse_button: 'browse',
    url: linkbased+'/bridge/uploadimage/',
    resize:{
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      crop: true,
      quality: 70
    },
    max_file_count: 5,
    filters:{
      mime_types: [{title: "Photo File", extensions: "jpg,png,jpeg,gif"}],
    }
});
```

I really need a hand with this problem since I have followed all the documentation but it does not work. I really appreciate any help. Thank you.

**Solved**

I change with version 2.3.6 and it works fine. Seems v.3.1.2 has a bug with resizing images but it works flawlessly with other features.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I expect to resize the image before its uploaded to the server. Sometimes my users complain a lot about the upload progress since the image size they upload is too big.

I do not get any exception/error in my console log. That is why I truly do not understand about this one. Do you think the code above should work?. @PaulStenne

Comment: go through the limitations section in the end of https://www.plupload.com/docs/v3/Image-Resizing-on-Client-Side

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I have set it. Would you help me to get out of this problem. I used dropzone last time and it works perfect. It resize image before its uploaded to the server. So, it would save user bandwith but using plupload does not work. @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: i just tried plupload jquery ui and it works correctly for me which version are you using for plupload and which ui are you using core or jquery ?

Comment: I am using 3.1.2, do you use the same version?

Comment: Hi, I have got the answer, thank you everyone. Have a great day!

Comment: i am using `2.3.6`